# Cant display a flash alert in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alert

I have a rails project where `users` can create `tournaments`.

I have this html page that takes to tournament#new

```
<div class="centre">

  <a href="<%=new_tournament_path%>"><button class= "btn-success">AJOUTER VOTRE TOURNOI <br><img src="/assets/trophy.svg" alt="trophy"></button></a>

</div>
```

I have 
in my `tournament_controller` I have :

```
def new 

    if current_user.first_name.blank? || current_user.last_name.blank? || current_user.judge_number.blank? || current_user.telephone.blank? || current_user.birthdate.blank? || current_user.iban.blank? || current_user.bic.blank? || current_user.address.blank? || current_user.iban.blank? || current_user.bic.blank?
       flash[:alert] = "Vous devez d'abord remplir <%= view_context.link_to 'votre profil', user_path(current_user) %> entièrement pour pouvoir ajouter votre tournoi"

      redirect_to 'judge_connected'

    elsif current_user.accepted == false
    flash[:alert] = "Votre compte Juge Arbitre doit d'abord avoir été accepté par l'équipe WeTennis avant de pouvoir ajouter un tournoi. Assurez vous d'avoir bien rempli intégralement<%= view_context.link_to 'votre profil', user_path(current_user) %> afin d'avoir une réponse rapide."
    redirect_to 'judge_connected'
    else
      create_mangopay_natural_user_and_wallet
      create_mangopay_bank_account

      @tournament = Tournament.new
      authorize @tournament
    end
  end
```

When the user's profile is complete, it works fine and takes me to tournament/new.
When the two first conditions are fulfilled, it redirects correctly to judge_connected but never displays the `flash alerts`

Here is the code of my flashes in views/shared/flashes(_flashes.html.erb)

```
<% if notice %>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible marginflashes" id="alert" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <%= notice.html_safe %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end%>

<% if alert %>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible marginflashes" id="alert" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <%= alert.html_safe %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I  noticed that if I actually refresh the page after I click on my button. The flash is actually appearing ! But I want it to show up without having to refresh the page.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code here to display a flash message. Your controller method just creates those messages as parameters; you need a view that displays them if you want to see it on a page. Do you have that code in a view somewhere?

Comment: A quick tip: You should look into [rails validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), in particular the validation on presence. It will help you clean up your controller code a bit.

Comment: I edited the description, flashes are working well everywhere else in the app...

Comment: Can you also add the code where you define your notice and alert methods?

Comment: @MariusPop I think that these methods are actually defined by rails

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code in your view file to display the flash alert. Something like this (taken from the [api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)):

`<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
  <% end %>`

You should probably put this in one of your layout files to keep it consistent across your application and to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Marius's answer, however what I personally like to do is the following...

add the following piece of code to your **application.html.erb** inside the **body**, so that this applies **globally** to all the views inside the application...

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Elegant and simple.

Now, in regards to receiving flash messages instantly on the same page, you'll have to look into doing it with Ajax, since this kind of action should be done asynchronously. Personally, I prefer not to do it, but rather redirect to the main page of the app, for instance, where the message would be shown.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: thanks, but I really need the message to be displayed on this very page, so I think Ill use AJAx in the end !

Comment: Yes I suppose in this case your best bet is using Ajax. I suggest you check out this [link](https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/3410235), you might find it very useful. All best!